# HEAD position in the example from git docs on stash command

Tags: git, git-reset

I have been reading [the examples](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html#_examples) of how `stash` command can ease the life and came across this code snippet:

```
# ... hack hack hack ...
$ git checkout -b my_wip
$ git commit -a -m "WIP"
$ git checkout master
$ edit emergency fix
$ git commit -a -m "Fix in a hurry"
$ git checkout my_wip
$ git reset --soft HEAD^
# ... continue hacking ...
```

As I get, what happens here is the following:

We create a new branch at the current commit:

```
--1
  |
  master
  my_wip
  HEAD
```

Then we stage modified files and make new commit to `my_wip` branch:

```
--1 ------------ 2
  |              |
  master         my_wip
                 HEAD
```

Then we checkout `master`:

```
--1 ------------ 2
  |              |
  master         my_wip
  HEAD
```

Then we modify some files and make a new commit (with preliminary staging (`-a` flag)):

```
                 HEAD
                 master
                 |
    -------------3
   /
  /
--1 ------------ 2
                 |
                 my_wip
```

Then we checkout `my_wip`:

```
                 master
                 |
    -------------3
   /
  /
--1 ------------ 2
                 |
                 my_wip
                 HEAD
```

Then we do `git reset --soft HEAD^`.

After this command I expect git to move `HEAD` to its previous position, namely `3` commit. So I expect it would get us into this stage (with working directory and staging area from `2` commit):

```
                 HEAD
                 master
                 my_wip
                 |
    -------------3
   /
  /
--1 ------------ 2
```

But as I'm getting from the docs, it does this (as after unstashing we should get to the position where we were when decided to stash):

```
                master
                 |
    -------------3
   /
  /
--1 ------------ 2
  |              
  my_wip
  HEAD
```

Does it mean that `HEAD^` is the previous position of the current branch and so it is dependent of the branch selected (I always thought that `HEAD^` is just the previous position of `HEAD` regardless of the current branch)? Or am I miscomprehending something?

Comment: I see a mistake in the question: `reset` should move branch pointer either with `HEAD`. I'll edit it right away. But this doesn't affect my question of where `HEAD^` is pointing to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `git` the concept `head` is not general. It is so that every `branch` has, so to say, its own `head` pointing normally to the last commit in the timeline for that branch.

On the other hand `HEAD` exists just once per repository and points to the head of the current branch, that is the current head.

So `HEAD` is always used within the context of your branch and not of the whole repository. That's the reason why `git reset --soft HEAD^` moves you one commit back and not to the previous position

If you take a look at the files within the `.git` folder you can clearly appreciate this concept:

```
.git/HEAD
```

This file contains a reference to the position where the HEAD (uppercase) of the repo is

```
.git/refs/heads
```

This folder contains one file for each branch with the reference to its head (lowercase). The previous file will usually point to one of these unless there is a `detached HEAD`

Comment: But there may be a detached `HEAD`. So, it may live without any branch at all.

Comment: OK! Thank you. So each branch has its own HEAD history. Wow!

Comment: HEAD doesn't really need a branch to live. Any way when entering in detached state git informs you with a note that that a special case is

Comment: actually each branch has its own head (lowercase) history, which you can see in `.git/logs/refs/heads`